# Proper way to backup and restore django project

Tags: mysql, django, ubuntu, virtualbox

I have been using `Oracle's virtual box` to setup an `Ubuntu 18.04LTS OS` to run my `django` application. The application is using `MySQL` as a database. The problem happened a few days ago, all my files suddenly **became read-only**, which is an indication of hard disk problems [as seen in this post.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/748821/all-files-and-folders-becomes-read-only)

I have since prepared another server to run the application, however I would like to know the proper procedures in migrating data to ensure that I don't loose any of my files. Could someone point me in the correct direction? Thank you.